# Using Apache Environment Variables to set custom ErrorDocument

Tags: apache-2.2, environment-variables, errordocument, setenv

I've got a set of RewriteCond rules that test for various mobile devices and then set environment variables like "env=device:.iphone" or "env=device:.smartphone" if the useragent matches an iPhone or Android device.

I'm trying to now redirect the user to custom-styled 404/500 server error pages for each device, by way of the error pages.

Ideally I'd like to be able to test for a variable being there, and then write in a custom ErrorDocument string.  But an apache  doesn't seem to work in this case.

Any ideas how I can construct if/else tests in an apache conf file for environment vars?

Answer (score 3):

Starting with version 2.3 of Apache, you can make use of IF constucts. It's [described in Apache's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#if).

Comment: Does this change the fact above that ErrorDocument currently (or at least on 2.2) doesn't allow for conditional processing?

Comment: Indeed a shame that it's not possible in 2.2, but it's worth the upgrade. Also, no mention of 2.2 as specific requirement.

Answer (score 1):

`ErrorDocument` doesn't allow for conditional anything, but it does do an internal redirect.

You should be able to accomplish this with mod_rewrite:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /normal_404.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:device:.iphone} 1
RewriteRule ^/normal_404.html$ /iphone_404.html [L]
```

Comment: thanks a bunch for this. However, it doesn't look like the rewrite rule has an effect on the errordocument.  Tried taking the condition off as well, to make sure, and no rewrite rules seem to apply to it.  Perhaps the rewrite rule needs to go into effect before the ErrorDocument is mapped?

Comment: The psudocode (psudoconfig) I was trying to do was something like:
`<if environment variable = iphone>
   ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/404.iphone.html
</if>`

I just haven't found a way in apache conf files to test for an environment variable - just to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers say that you should be able to use Apache 2.3's [<If>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#if) condition, but don't give an example or explain the syntax.   Here is how you would check an environment variable and then set a custom error document based on it in *.htaccess*:

```
<If "reqenv('device') == 'iphone'">
     ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/404.iphone.html
</If>
```